# R How to loop over paired columns to create new columns

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to loop over specific pair columns (they have similar names) and create columns based on a conditional statement.

Example dataset:

```
    set.seed(2)
    df <- data.frame (id=rep(1:5),
                      s1=rnorm(5, 0, 3),
                      s2=rnorm(5, 0, 3),
                      s2a=rnorm(5, 0, 3),
                      st1=rnorm(5, 3, 3),
                      st2=rnorm(5, 3, 3),
                      st2a=rnorm(5, 3, 3))


> df
  id         s1         s2       s2a       st1        st2      st2a
1  1 -2.6907436  0.3972609  1.252952 -3.933207  9.2724576 -4.355119
2  2  0.5545476  2.1238642  2.945258  5.635814 -0.5997775  4.431712
3  3  4.7635360 -0.7190941 -1.178086  3.107420  7.7689146  1.210325
4  4 -3.3911270  5.9534218 -3.119007  6.038486  8.8639549  5.376610
5  5 -0.2407553 -0.4163610  5.346687  4.296795  3.0148133  3.868910
```

Column s1 is paired with column st1 etc. I want to indicate 1/0 if the equality between these columns is -3 to 0. E.g. `df$ys1<-ifelse(df$s1<=-3 & df$st1>=0, 1, 0)`. The ultimate aim is to create the final variable `yes_no` (1/0) to indicate if any of the differences between the pairs of columns are 1 e.g. `df$yes_no<-ifelse(df$ys1==1 | df$ys2==1 | df$ys2a==1, 1, 0)`

The new dataset should look like this:

```
> df
  id         s1         s2       s2a       st1        st2      st2a ys1 ys2 ys2a yes_no
1  1 -2.6907436  0.3972609  1.252952 -3.933207  9.2724576 -4.355119   0   0    0      0
2  2  0.5545476  2.1238642  2.945258  5.635814 -0.5997775  4.431712   0   0    0      0
3  3  4.7635360 -0.7190941 -1.178086  3.107420  7.7689146  1.210325   0   0    0      0
4  4 -3.3911270  5.9534218 -3.119007  6.038486  8.8639549  5.376610   1   0    1      1
5  5 -0.2407553 -0.4163610  5.346687  4.296795  3.0148133  3.868910   0   0    0      0
```

I'm sure there is a way of doing a loop without actually creating all additional columns (i.e. just create the final column, `yes_no` ) but I would be interested in how to create these just to know how to do it, in addition to a neater method. 
I think a way of doing it would be to break up the dataset into two sets based on the pairs and then use in a loop:

```
firstt<-(df[,c(2:4)])
final<-(df[,c(5:7)])
```

or skip that and try directly in a loop

```
for(i in names(df[,c(2:4)])){
r<-(df[,c(5:7)])
df[i] <-ifelse(df$[i]<=-3 & df$[r]>=0, 1, 0)
}
```

Obviously that wont work but that is the idea of what I was trying. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution in base R:

```
df$yes_no <- 
  rowSums(mapply(function(i,r)
    ifelse(df[[r]]<=-3 & df[[i]]>=0, 1, 0)
  ,  grep("st",names(df),value=TRUE),
  gsub("t","",grep("st",names(df),value=TRUE))))  >0
```

1- I amusing regex to extract names. You can use indices here also. $X

```
X = "st1"  "st2"  "st2a"

Y = "s1"  "s2"  "s2a"
```

2- I am using  `mapply` to apply to the paired elemend ( first elt of X and first element of Y and so ..)

3- rowSums to aggregate the 3 columns in one  , and >0 to convert it to a logical vector

Comment: thanks but there is a small error, the final column is slightly different to the one I have given above?

Comment: @user63230 yes but I have used your condition.

Comment: you just need to switch the i and r in the ifelse statement and it works: ifelse(df[[r]]<=-3 & df[[i]]>=0, 1, 0)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution with for loops

```
a <- names(df[,c(2:4)])
b <- names(df[,c(5:7)])
for(i in seq_along(a)){
df$temp<-ifelse(df[,names(df)[names(df)==a[i]]]<=-3 & df[,names(df)[names(df)==b[i]]]>=0, 1, 0)
names(df)[names(df)=="temp"] <- paste0("ys", i)
}

df$yes_no <- apply(df[grep("ys", names(df))]==1,1,  function(k) ifelse(TRUE %in% k, 1, 0) )

print(df)
  id         s1         s2       s2a       st1        st2      st2a ys1 ys2 ys3 yes_no
1  1 -2.6907436  0.3972609  1.252952 -3.933207  9.2724576 -4.355119   0   0   0      0
2  2  0.5545476  2.1238642  2.945258  5.635814 -0.5997775  4.431712   0   0   0      0
3  3  4.7635360 -0.7190941 -1.178086  3.107420  7.7689146  1.210325   0   0   0      0
4  4 -3.3911270  5.9534218 -3.119007  6.038486  8.8639549  5.376610   1   0   1      1
5  5 -0.2407553 -0.4163610  5.346687  4.296795  3.0148133  3.868910   0   0   0      0
```

Comment: Glad to help with the problem!